# Can I test "drawable" taken from Url Stream for being a proper icon?

Tags: android, caching, android-listview

Im working on caching for images of my listview. 
I have used the solution from  [here](http://pivotallabs.com/users/tyler/blog/articles/1754-android-image-caching)

The problem im having is - how to set a default image if icon does not exist?

The url to images is returning a server page that the image does not exist on the server. So im guessing that this html page is then somehow converted to faulty Drawable -> so that IOexception does not happen (coz some data is returned).

Can I test "drawable" for being a proper icon?.

or maybe my logic is false here. Please advise

Code from ListViewAdapter :

```
     try {
            URL url = new URL("http:// some image url here.jpg");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(true);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(connection.getInputStream(), "src");

            viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaulticon);
            }
```

Comment: check its lazyloading :http://sspower3.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `drawable` variable will be `null` if it can't be decoded from stream. Check for `null` and set your default image.

```
Drawable drawable = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http:// some image url here.jpg");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(true);
    // try to load and decode
    drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(connection.getInputStream(), "src");

    if(drawable != null) // if succeed - set drawable
        viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ignore IOException if any...
} finally {
    if(drawable == null) // If drawable are null (not decoded or failed to load (404?))
        viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaulticon); // set default image
}
```

Comment: pfff..so obvious.. think i need a cup of coffee . thanks Olegas!